# Realtime C programming vicInstallHandler need help to understand

Tags: c, vector, real-time, handler, irq

Ive been to i need to understand this code in significantly more detail than the comments, can soemone help?

```
void vicInstallIRQhandler(pVoidFunc_t pISR, uint32_t priority,
                      uint32_t vicIntSource) {

 // store the handler address in the correct slot in the vector 

 *(&VICVECTADDR0 + vicIntSource) = (unsigned long)pISR;

 // set the priority of the interrupt for this slot

 *(&VICVECTPRIORITY0 + vicIntSource) = priority;

 // clear FIQ select bit i.e. assign this interrupt source to IRQ

 VICINTSELECT &= ~(1UL << vicIntSource);

 // enable the interrupt

 VICINTENABLE |= (1UL << vicIntSource);
}
```

Comment: This really depends on the specification of your device. The comments are pretty explanatory. Maybe you should post a more specific questions about the parts you don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the comments are pretty good. However, I give a try to explain more. 
Overall, the function set up interrupt handler, described by a pointer to the actual service routine `pISR`, it's priority, and the index of the (physical) interrupt.

At your CPU, the addresses and the corresponding priorities are stored in tables with the start addresses `VICVECTADDR0` and `VICVECTPRIORITY0`, resp. The correct table entry is found by adding the interrupt index to the base address.

`VICINTSELECT` and `VICINTENABLE` are bit vectors, where the bit addressed by the interrupt index is set and unset, resp. The semantic of `VICINTSELECT` is to tell the CPU that there exist a service routine for the interrupt (clear bit). The semantic of `VICINTENABLE` is to tell the CPU that the interrupt is not masked, i.e. enabled (set bit).

I hope my explanation helps a bit.

Answer (score -1):

@Wrekaar What makes you think it'll be verbatim? We'll probably juggle the wording around abit before we copy-paste it (jokes)